# Periodic boundary condition and Runge-Kutta method of order 4 used in solving Partial Differential Equation(1D Wave packet equation).

Tags: numerical-methods, python, runge-kutta-methods

I have to code for the problem of solving 1D wave packet propagation with equation given as:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + c\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$
The initial solution is given as: u(x, 0) = $$ e^{(\alpha(x−x0 )^2)}cos(k_0(x − x_0))$$ with ${\alpha} = -5 $ and ${x_0} = 5.0$.Tangent hyperbolic function(double sided) is used as grid. I need to solve the above equation using *Runge Kutta of order 4* for time discretisation with **periodic boundary conditions**. I know that while getting matrices for solving derivatives is correct and the periodic boundary conditions are applied properly. But during application of RK4 method I am bit unsure if the periodic conditions are applied properly.

Spatial discretisation algo have *derivative* terms considering three points on RHS : **j-1, j and j+1**
N is the number of nodes in the grid.
Derivative term is written as **ddisp** in the code.
It is the part of code where RK4 is used.

```
# RK4         
# disp = u0 # initial condition array
flag = True
#h = 0
timeee = 0.000
timemax = 5001 #ms
while(timeee<timemax):
    predisp = np.zeros(N+4)
    ddisp = np.zeros(N+2) # derivative of displacement
    k1 = np.zeros(N)
    K2 = np.zeros(N)
    K3 = np.zeros(N)
    K4 = np.zeros(N)
    # stage 1
    for l in range (0,N):
        predisp[l+2] = u0[l]

    predisp[N+1] = predisp[3]
    predisp[N+2] = predisp[3]
    predisp[N+3] = predisp[4]
    predisp[3] = predisp[N]
    predisp[0] = predisp[N-1]

    for p in range (0,N):
        ddisp[p+1] = uj_prime[p]

    ddisp[N+1] = ddisp[3]
    ddisp[N] = ddisp[3]
    ddisp[0] = ddisp[N+1]     

    for i in range(1,N+1):
        k1[i-1] = -c*ddisp[i]
    k1[N-1] = k1[0]

    for y in range (0,N-1):
        u0[y] = predisp[y+2]+ 0.5*(dt/a_sec)*k1[y]
    u0[N-1] = u0[0]

    #Stage 2
    u_initial_colmat = np.transpose(u0)    
    uj_prime = C @ u_initial_colmat

    for k in range(0,N):
        ddisp[k+1] = uj_prime[k]
    ddisp[N+1] = ddisp[3]
    ddisp[N] = ddisp[3]
    ddisp[0] = ddisp[N+1]    

    for i in range(1,N+1):
        K2[i-1] = -c*ddisp[i]
    K2[N-1] = K2[0]
    

    for y in range(0,N-1):
        u0[y] = predisp[y+2] + 0.5*(dt/a_sec)*K2[y]
    u0[N-1] = u0[0]    

    #Stage 3
    u_initial_colmat = np.transpose(u0)    
    uj_prime = C @ u_initial_colmat

    for k in range(0,N):
        ddisp[k+1] = uj_prime[k]
    ddisp[N+1] = ddisp[3]
    ddisp[N] = ddisp[3]
    ddisp[0] = ddisp[N+1] 

    for i in range(1,N+1):
        K3[i-1] = -c*ddisp[i]
    K3[N-1] = K3[0]   


    for y in range(0,N-1):
        u0[y] = predisp[y+2] + 1.0*(dt/a_sec)*K3[y]
    u0[N-1] = u0[0]
    #Stage 4
    u_initial_colmat = np.transpose(u0)    
    uj_prime = C @ u_initial_colmat

    for k in range(0,N):
        ddisp[k+1] = uj_prime[k]
    ddisp[N+1] = ddisp[3]
    ddisp[N] = ddisp[3]
    ddisp[0] = ddisp[N+1]    

    for i in range(1,N+1):
        K4[i-1] = -c*ddisp[i]
    K4[N-1] = K4[0]
    
    for y in range(0,N-1):
        u0[y] = predisp[y+2] + (1/6)*(dt/a_sec)*(k1[y] + 2*K2[y] + 2*K3[y] + K4[y])  
    u0[N-1] = u0[0]

    milli_time = timeee/a_sec        
    uu =  ((np.exp(alpha*((x-c*milli_time-x0)**2))*(np.cos(k0*(x-c*milli_time-x0))))) # Analytical Solution
    timeee = timeee + dt
    if (timeee >= timemax):
            exit()
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is `C`?  What do you mean with "use the hyperbolic tangent as grid"?

Comment: c is the wave speed while the spatial array follows a tangent hyperbolic function. you can refer to this for grid [link](https://caefn.com/cfd/hyperbolic-tangent-stretching-grid)@LutzLehmann

Comment: No, I mean the uppercase `C` in `uj_prime = C @ u_initial_colmat`. // The periodic boundary conditions contradict somewhat the anisotropic grid, as the solution will rotate with speed `c` through every grid position.

Comment: Actually, A was a matrix containing all the coefficients of the derivative terms of 'u' stencil used for spatial discretisation and B was a matrix containing coefficients of 'u' used in the stencil. C is the matrix we obtain from A^(-1)*B. You could also refer to the paper "Hybrid sixth order spatial discretization scheme for non-uniform
Cartesian grids". Could you please elaborate on "The periodic boundary conditions contradict somewhat the anisotropic grid, as the solution will rotate with speed c through every grid position."? @LutzLehmann

Comment: The whole system can be continued periodically. The solution just shifts the initial function along the space axis. There is no special place on the space axis that stays a special place for long. Thus there is no reason to have any anisotropic, that is, not equidistant, discretization.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will take your suggestion into consideration. But, I am more concerned about the application of periodic boundary condition and it's effect on the code for time discretisation using the RK4 method. If you have any suggestions or ideas, kindly share them. @LutzLehmann

Comment: I'm not sure you have to do anything. The periodic wrap-around should already be present in the matrix `C`, so that all that remains is an ordinary linear system of DE. // Btw., I'm not saying that it is wrong to use the non-equidistant mesh, just that one might not see the otherwise expected advantages.